# org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper throwing IllegalArgumentException: Can not set Double field to java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Upgraded existing API to use Neo4j 4.3.3 and `neo4j-ogm-http-driver` to 3.2.25. `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` is `2.3.4.Release`. Now if I try to create/fetch a relationship with one of the attribute as Double  using `org.springframework.data.repository` `CrudRepository.save()` and `org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository` `Neo4jRepository.findById()`, it throws below error:

> Found relationship type: OWNS to map to RelationshipEntity: RelationshipEntityName
> 2021-08-21 00:25:14.780 ERROR 3556 --- [nio-8303-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Error mapping GraphModel; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel] with root cause

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Double field RelationshipEntityName.percentage to java.math.BigDecimal
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.FieldInfo.lambda$write$0(FieldInfo.java:352)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.FieldInfo.write(FieldInfo.java:349)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.FieldInfo.write(FieldInfo.java:383)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:305)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:268)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.createRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:409)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(GraphEntityMapper.java:354)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationships(GraphEntityMapper.java:330)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapContentOf(GraphEntityMapper.java:158)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.lambda$map$2(GraphEntityMapper.java:115)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphRowModelMapper.map(GraphRowModelMapper.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.lambda$executeAndMap$1(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:590)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:564)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.executeAndMap(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:150)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:425)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$1(SharedSessionCreator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invokeInTransaction(SharedSessionCreator.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:123)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.doExecute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.findByResource(Unknown Source)
```

I tried changing the attribute percentage to Number, that does not throw the exception but percentage doesn't get saved.
I do not want to upgrade `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` to any major version at this point.
Upgrading to `Spring-Data-Neo4j` 6.x will again be big migration effort.
I am stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the exact place where the error was coming from was `neo4j.ogm.core` files, I tried various versions of the jar but nothing worked.
Finally I resolved the problem by writing a custom converter as the implicit converter was not able to convert between Double and BigDecimal.

```
public class PercentageConverter implements AttributeConverter<Double, BigDecimal> {
  @Override
    public BigDecimal toGraphProperty(Double value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new BigDecimal(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Double toEntityAttribute(BigDecimal value) {
        return value.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

and annotate the entity attribute to use this converter

```
@Convert(PercentageConverter.class)
```

This resolved my error and now I can do all CRUD operations successfully

Comment: Thanks for that fix. This worked for me locally so i don't get the exception when connecting to a local neo4j instance, but it doesn't work when connecting to an Aura instance. I get a "class cast" exception, although this code does not contain a cast. So, I am thinking if must be coming from the libraries used to communicate with the remote instance.